# Docker не устанавливает контейнеры

Tags: docker

Попытался устаовить контейнер с apache, но docker выдает ошибку: Step 2/3 : COPY src/ /var/www/html/ COPY failed: CreateFile \?C:ProgramDataDocker mpdocker-builder462657596src: The system cannot find the file specified.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Dockerfile:

FROM php:7.2-apache

COPY src/ /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80

Comment: А папка src/ на месте?

Comment: обозначте workdir , очень похоже что у вас попросту не верно указан путь к папке src